# Htaccess Redirect with GET Variable

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I've been searching and searching for an answer and decided it may be best to ask. I am trying to redirect the following:

```
redirect 301 /store/?p=3m_controltac http://www.designtoprint.com/3m-controltac
```

I know it has something to do with using a GET variable but every example I've tried ends without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do this with `Redirect` directive as it does not work with GET variables. Your best choice is to use **mod_rewrite** (or implement it in your webpage (e.g. php file) directly):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =p=3m_controltac
RewriteRule ^store/$ http://www.designtoprint.com/3m-controltac? [R=301,L]
```

This will redirect (using 301 code) from `/store/?p=3m_controltac` to `http://www.designtoprint.com/3m-controltac` ONLY (no other URLs will be affected).